# Itemized PayPal Checkout using Angular (ngCart)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal, shopping-cart, checkout

I'm attempting to use PayPal to check out and show an itemized list of the products. I can get the cart to work showing a total for the amount of items added to the cart, but since they aren not itemized the seller will not know which items were ordered.

I'm using [ngCart](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs) for my shopping cart. I've followed the docs and I believe that I've configured everything correctly, but when I click "checkout" using the itemized PayPal process my cart is empty in PayPal. The items in my store are listed as such:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="product in products">
  <div class="col s3 right">
    <ngcart-addtocart id="{{product._id}}" name="{{product.title}}" price="{{product.price}}" quantity-max="5" quantity="1">
      <i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>
    </ngcart-addtocart>
  </div>
```

I took a look at the [PayPal docs](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside#methodtwo) and it appears as if ngCart is configured to provide the necessary information. Here is how the actual checkout form submits to PayPal (this is where I believe something is wrong)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" ng-show="ngCart.getTotalItems()" target="_top">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input name="business" type="hidden" value="storeEmail@gmail.com"/>
    <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="CA"/>
    <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="{{ settings.paypal.item_name }}"/>
    <input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="{{ settings.paypal.item_number }}"/>
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="{{ ngCart.getSubTotal()}}"/>
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="{{ settings.paypal.currency_code }}"/>
    <input name="button_subtype" type="hidden" value="services"/>
    <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="{{ settings.paypal.no_note }}"/>
    <input name="tax_rate" type="hidden" value="{{ ngCart.getTaxRate()}}"/>
    <input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="{{ ngCart.getShipping()}}"/>
    <input name="image_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:1337/images/logo.png"/>
    <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"/>
    <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" border="0" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_paynow_cc_144x47.png" type="image"/>
  </form>
```

After reading the PayPal docs the form fields, such as item_name for example, need to be saved as `item_name_1, item_price_1, item_shipping_1, item_name_2`, etc... If I hard code the values into the form then it works, but since I have multiple products I need this process to post based on the items added in ngCart, if that makes sense.

Products in Cart:
[image: Items in the Cart]

Checkout using `<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick"/>` in PayPal. As you can see, this isn't itemized, but the total is correct and it recognizes the items in the cart:
[image]

Checkout using `<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart"/>` to itemize the cart. This is showing that the cart is empty:
[image]

I hope my description of the problem was clear. If not, please let me know and I'll provide more information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the checkout button's element when you load up the cart view with items added to your cart? Your second snippet of code should appear there, but with values like the amount and business filled in. If they are, then it means that ngCart has info on those items stored. Otherwise, I'd check to verify that it's actually storing the information correctly from your "Add to Cart" button.

Comment: Additionally (not sure if relevant), I just learned today that the documentation is slightly off, and the settings should be listed as `{paypal: {business: "business@email.com", item_name: "itemName", etc...}}` rather than just `{business: "business@email.com", item_name: "itemName", etc...}`. This was causing me to go to an invalid paypal page when the checkout button was clicked.

Comment: Thanks @NateFrueh ! This was the issue after all. Great catch!

Comment: I'm sorry for reopening this, but where can I change the settings to appear like that?

Comment: No worries @AdamSilva. Here is the link to my GitHub repo containing the modified file for the cart. 

https://github.com/mguenther006/doggieOasis/blob/master/public/template/ngCart/cart.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @MattG. did you fixed the itemized view? I am having the same issue. I looked into your code and can't seem to find how you fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Hi! I did not, however Nate Frueh's response above looks like it may resolve the issue.

Comment: where is that json data located?