# ngCart PayPal checkout page ask for purchase details for cart

Tags: paypal, form-submit, shopping-cart

This question might be related to [Itemized PayPal Checkout using Angular (ngCart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402477/itemized-paypal-checkout-using-angular-ngcart)

I'm trying to use ngcart http://ngcart.snapjay.com/cart to add a shopping cart to my website.

I have a working checkout page which has an itemised list of products.

[image]

Inspecting the checkout button's element when you load up the cart view with items added to the cart gives this:

```
<ngcart-checkout template-url="/templates/ngCart/checkout.html" service="paypal" settings="{ url:'/shop/checkout', paypal: { business: 'paypal_email', item_number:'123', currency_code:'GBP'}}" class="ng-isolate-scope">
```

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" ng-show="ngCart.getTotalItems()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal_email" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.7" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="20" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="2.5" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

When I click the Buy Now button I'm redirected to this page where it asks purchase details and lists the sub total before tax and shipping has been added.

[image]

In the ngCart example http://ngcart.snapjay.com/ when you checkout it goes to the standard PayPal page without asking for item details and has a Pay with Debit or Credit Card option which displays the correct total.

[image]

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I don't have a lot of experience with PayPal checkout so any help is appreciated. I was wondering if it is to do with the PayPal account itself? Does it need to be a business account with express checkout enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research it looks like the ngCart is only designed to send the aggregate cart amount to PayPal and not an itemised order.

I have updated the checkout.html template to add the contents of the cart as individual items.

```
<div ng-if="service=='paypal'">
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" ng-show="ngCart.getTotalItems()">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{ settings.paypal.business }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA" /> 
    <ng-form name="cartItems" ng-repeat="item in ngCart.getCart().items track by $index">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_{{$index+1}}" value="{{item.getName()}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_{{$index+1}}" value="{{item.getPrice()}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_{{$index+1}}" value="{{item.getQuantity()}}" />         
        <ng-form name="shipping" ng-if="$last">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_{{$index+2}}" value="Shipping" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_{{$index+2}}" value="{{ngCart.getShipping()}}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_{{$index+2}}" value="1" />  
        </ng-form>          
    </ng-form>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="{{ settings.paypal.currency_code }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="{{ settings.paypal.no_note }}" />       
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

This appears to be working as I have sent a test order and received an email listing the individual items and quantities.

Answer (score 1):

The value for the parameter **item_name** is empty. Please make it to "Sample Product". It will redirect you to login page.

Cheers!

Comment: <ngcart-checkout template-url="/templates/ngCart/checkout.html" service="paypal" settings="{ url:'/shop/checkout', paypal: { business: 'paypal_email', item_name: 'Sample Product', currency_code:'GBP' }}"></ngcart-checkout>